# Copy-PnPFile returns File Not Found

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, migration

I am writing a PowerShell script that copys all files from one document library to a different one in SharePoint Online.

I can't get my head around the behavior.

When I copy the whole folder, then all the files get copied and it works fine:

```
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl "Old Library/" -TargetUrl "NewLibrary/"
```

This does not help me though, because I need to log each file and I can't do it this way. So I need to copy each file individually.

When I copy the files individually, I get an error message "File Not Found":

```
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl "Old Library/item.docx" -TargetUrl "NewLibrary/item.docx"
```

I have already tried using different paths:

- relative to site
- relative to root
- full domain

Anybody has got an idea what the problem might be?
How can I copy the files and log individual files (name, path, success)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Copy-PnPFile cmdlet isn’t working correctly and an issue has been raised in the PnP PowerShell GitHub repo.

This has been ongoing for about a month now, but a fix should be introduced shortly.

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/2103

Answer (score 1):

I've faced with the same issue and found only one working way to copy files via Copy-PnPFile across site collections within the same tenant: copy whole root folder:

```
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl Documents -TargetUrl /sites/otherproject/Documents -SkipSourceFolderName
```

However it will also try to copy allitems.aspx. So full solution will be this:

```
$error = $null
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl Documents -TargetUrl /sites/otherproject/Documents -SkipSourceFolderName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable error
if ($error -and !$error.Exception.Message.ToLower().Contains("allitems.aspx")) {
    throw $error
}
```

Comment: thank you for the workaround. I need to copy files individually so they can be logged.